# Sending ajax request to PHP as GET, but parsing response as XML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I using $.ajax method in jquery to implement an ajax call on a PHP file. I want to submit 2 parameters to the PHP file which will return response as XML. This is what I am trying to do:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'server.php',
 dataType: 'xml',
 data: {
  'param1' : '2',
  'param2': '3'
 },
 success: function(data) {
  alert('success');
  // do something with xml returned...
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  alert(xhr.status);
  alert(xhr.responseText);
 }
 });
```

In the PHP file I've simply done this for debugging:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>vala</a>
<b>valb</b>';
die;
```

This returns an error and I receive two alerts, one says "200" and the other shows the XML shown above. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your xml output is not vaild instead of

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <a>vala</a>
 <b>valb</b>';
 die;


echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<a>vala</a>
<b>valb</b> 
</root>';
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

200 means everything is OK.

Try adding `header('Content-type: text/xml');` to the top of server.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `die;` to `exit();`

Edit: my bad that's not right